# Python Gurobi import error: DLL load failed

Tags: python, windows, gurobi

I have installed Gurobi on my Windows 10 machine and I'm trying to use it in Python. Trying to import `import gurobipy` yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gurobipy
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gurobipy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Running `gurobi` from the command line works fine.

What does `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your trace I see

```
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
```

which suggests that you are using a 32 bit build of Python 3.7.  However current Gurobi distributions only ship with a `gurobipy` Python extension compiled for 64 bit Python versions.  You need to use a 64 bit Python build to use the `gurobipy` extension.